# Yii2 Framework - Custom Installation Template

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

When I access to Yiisoft account on Github:

```
https://github.com/yiisoft
```

I see 3 pinned repos: Yii2, Yii2-app-basic and Yii2-app-advanced.

I know When I run the command:

```
composer create-project [template] [project-name]
```

I can create a project using one of installation templates. Also I know on the composer.json on this templates is set yii2 framework and yii2 bootstrap as dependencies, so they get downloaded.

What about if I want to create my own installation template, is there a guide how to do it?. I know it would not be that productive but just wondering out of curiosity.

**UPDATE**
I have noticed that just a couple hours ago this page was published:http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-start-from-scratch.html
but still it is based on the basic installation template, not a totally custom one.

Comment: there's no guide that i know of that starts from nothing, there is however a comprehensive guide explaining in depth the [Application structure](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html) (don't skip this guide), after that you can also check out other starter apps & templates on github for ideas [githubjeka/yii2-rest](https://github.com/githubjeka/yii2-rest), [samdark/yii2-minimal](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-minimal)

Comment: @csminb Thanks for the links, I will review them!